# javascript unicode property from c#

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, unicode

Im using this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var breadCrumps = $('.breadcrumb');
    breadCrumps.find('span').text("<%= ArticleSectionData.title %>");
});
```

title is a property which has values encoded in unicode (I think). These are Greek letters. On the local IIS developer server (embedded in visual studio), the characters are displayed in correct way but, on the test server they appear as:

`&#931;`

Do You know any solution for this problem ?

Thanks for help

EDIT:

I have changed the code a little bit:

```
breadCrumps.find('span').text(<%= ArticleSectionData.title %>);
```

And now it works correctly, encoding is frustrating ...

Comment: Please use [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) instead to avoid XSS.

Comment: how text is going to avoid XSS ? Im getting data from the server so I think there is no need for doing that. In fact with /html it works correctly while with .text it fails on encoding

Comment: .html sets the innerHTML. If `ArticleSection.title` is based on user-input, and they made a title of `<script>somethingbad</script>` - then you are going to execute the script. `.text()` will display the actual script because the `script` tag will be escaped.

Comment: Ok, but the content doesnt depend on the user. Admin inserts it to the database

Comment: Wait, which is it?  It works in dev, but not test?  Or, it works with `.html()`, but not `.text()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are working off of a different database in test than in dev, then I suspect the issue is with the data.  If you are storing [HTML entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_entities#Character_references) (eg, `&#931;`) in your database, then you need to use `.html()`.  If you are storing actual unicode characters (eg, `Σ`) in the database, then you need to use `.text()`.  The way to represent `Σ` in html is with `&#931;`.  But if you set the text of an element to `&#931;`, it displays that literally - the innerHTML of that element would contain `&amp;#931;`.

Comment: "If you are storing actual unicode characters (eg, Σ)." How can I know if Im storing unicode characters or HTML entities? What is the difference in the way databse holds these two options ?

Comment: @gruber - The string "&#931;" is not meaningful to a database - Ie, it doesn't represent a unicode character within the database - it only represents a unicode character in HTML, XML, etc.  So, either your database is storing the HTML entity string "&#931;" or it is storing the actual unicode character "Σ".  Just do a `SELECT myField FROM myTable` and look at the output to see which it contains.  You'll see either "Σ" or "&#931;".

Answer (score 0):

I don't know root of problem, but you can use this http://www.strictly-software.com/htmlencode for decode `&#931;` to Sigma